# what goes into a minimal stack.yaml file?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have projects compiling with `cabal build` (but using `hpack` for the convenience). For some reason, I would like to compile them with `stack build`. What goes into a minimal `stack.yaml` file?

The stack documentation gives details what goes into such a file, but does not show a minimal (or any, as much as I can see) example. I fear to use `stack init` on an existing project for unintended consequences.

What is a small example from which to go?

Comment: I believe specifying the resolver should be sufficient, e.g. `resolver: lts-19.16`. AFAIK `packages` defaults to the current directory, i.e. `packages: .`.

Comment: I found that my fears for unintended consequences running `stack init` on an existing project were unfounded; indeed it does work and produces a starting skeleton.

Comment: @sjakobi: I guess this is correct. Thus the minimal file is nearly trivial - which is not obvious unless you know how stack works.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal `stack.yaml`:

```
resolver: lts-19.16 # for ghc 9.0.2 newest lts

packages:
- .
```

A not-so minimal skeleton from which to expand:

```
resolver: lts-19.16 # for ghc 9.0.2 newest lts

packages:
- .
 
extra-deps:  # include here other local packages

ghc-options:
  "$everything": -haddock # to produce documentation with haddock
```